# What should I do to help my writing flow?

Tags: creative-writing

I am writing a story (fiction) about *all gods* of *all mythologies*, including some new gods. I only have three pages written, and need to write faster. My deadline is in exactly 2 months, and i have to have 500 pages. I have to have 500 pages, or my publisher will not pay me as much.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you clarify the problem you're having? If you're looking to write faster, check out this question ([Ways to speed up my writing to 15 - 20 pages a day](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/7551/34330)) and let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's almost 10 pages a day… This goal may not be realistic.

Comment: Maybe 80's Stephen King has some advice

Comment: If your publisher is willing to promise you money regardless of quality (and writing that fast will not get you quality, beta reading, or even a chance to edit) then they kind of get what they deserve. Something about this seems funny, but it also doesn't sound like you're an established writer. Pardon for asking, but what's the story? Are you famous or something? Otherwise I'm a little worried someone's scamming you.

Comment: Yeah, this "publisher" sounds like a scammer. Have they asked you for money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off your phone, and any pop-ups on your computer.
Find some relaxing music, and make sure nobody is calling You.

I am 99% off-line, when I write, that makes me write +3000 words a day.

Then do a short version, like the bones of the whale.
Write down the names, and the short description of each god.
That should take the first month, and then go back over it, and fill it out.

It is never pages that counts, because the page might be tightly fitted A4 or a larger print, booklet size.